# ImportError: No module named jumpssh

Tags: python, pip, paramiko

I am trying to import the jumpssh library with the pip command, but it is showing module not found. However, I already downloaded the package library.

```
$ pip list |grep -i jumpssh
jumpssh      1.6.5
 $ python
Python 2.7.5 (default, Nov 16 2020, 22:23:17)
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-44)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import jumpssh
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named jumpssh
>>>


>>> import paramiko
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named paramiko
>>>
```

Comment: you sure you installed those libraries properly before? like `>pip install paramiko` or however those libraries said you should install them

Comment: another issue could be that you have multiple versions of python on your system, and the `pip` command is linked to one of those other while the `python` is for your 2.7.5, in that case run pip as `>python -m pip` that should run the pip from that specific python and install those libraries with that